# App Engine httplib.HTTPConnection deadline

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Since App Engine's **httplib** is simply wrapped around their own **urlfetch**, I'm wondering how to set the default urlfetch timeout to the allowed maximum 10 seconds **so that it will affect httplib.HTTPConnection**.

I can't directly set the timeout on HTTPConnection, as GAE uses 2.5. 2.6 added the timeout param.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you can do anything other than subclassing `httplib` or providing your own copy (perhaps back-ported from 2.6+).

Comment: Actually, to me it seems that the 10 seconds timeout is set on the `socket` level, how do you change that with `urlfetch`?

Comment: Is there a great reason to use `httplib` instead of `urlfetch` directly?  You can set the timeout deadline with an argument to the [urlfetch.fetch()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction.html) function -- `fetch('url', deadline=10)`.

Comment: @AttilaOláh The URLFetch deadline has nothing to do with socket; you can't use socket on App Engine.

Comment: @NickJohnson Ok, you got me there. For some reason I thought that the deadline is set on the socket level, without realising that the URLFetch itself is a service that you access through an API. How silly of me.

Comment: @CodyHess: Yes, avoiding dependence on Google's API is one of them.

Comment: If anyone feels like tinkering with something truly wicked: try timeouts on App Engine. Write a handler that responds after sleeping 3 seconds. Access that via a different handler (e.g. like here, with httplib). Modify urlfetch timeout, modify the sleep time -- see what you get. The responses seemed to be totally inconsistent and unpredictable when I was playing around with (though it was mild fun) it. Just pointing, in case anyone finds out they have too much time on their hands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried changing the default urlfetch deadline?

```
import urlfetch
urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(10)
```

Comment: Thanks. And sorry, this was an annoying problem I kept running into but later wandered off to work on a completely different projet, forgetting about this.